# Utilizing the click on point event

Tags: javascript, shieldui

I want to know how I could utilize the point click event on the Shield UI Chart? 
What I need is to show a message to the user, consisting of the point's value and some text.

Comment: post the code that you are talking about, and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code that uses the event of a point being clicked on a Shield UI Chart:

```
   events: {
    pointSelect: function pointSelectHandler(args) {

    var Information= "Point Value: " + args.point.y;    
    alert(Information);
    },
```

Don't forget to enable the point selection:

```
       enablePointSelection:true,
```